# Installing Linux Mint in Virtual Box Win10 Kernel panic

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualbox, linux-mint

I need to install Linux Mint in Virtual Box.

I installed Virtual Box. Downloaded the Linux Mint 64-bit ISO file.
I started a new machine in Virtual Box called it "Linux Mint", type Linux, Version other Linux (64-bit).
No problem so far. Then I configured all the stuff they ask you.

Now. I started the machine and entered the previously downloaded file `linuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit`.
That works, then the Virtual Box screen comes up, quickly after that it changes to the Linux Mint start screen saying "Welcome to Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon 64-bit" and below that options what to do. First of them is "Start Linux Mint".

If I either wait for it to boot automatically or click "Start Linux Mint" it takes a second and then comes up with the error message:

> Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found. Try passing init=
> option to kernel.

I don't know what that means. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 23):

The issue has been resolved!

The ISO wasn’t corrupted, I just had to give the virtual machine more RAM. The suggested 512MB weren’t enough, I upped it to about 1.5GB and then it just worked.

Comment: Good suggestion, terrible error message. :-)